# Errors with visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Every time I start coding in visual studio c# i am getting this error in my form:
[image]

and if i click "Ignor and continue" all my work in my form is been deleted.

*zoom in to see the image*

Comment: Go to the designer file and delete that `textbox1_TextChanged` from line 53.

Comment: Open the .designer.cs file in the text editor and remove line 53....

Comment: "zoom in to see the image"... no. Images are not bad, but including the *text* of the error message is important.

Comment: Never ever click ignore and continue...ever...

Comment: this error happens all the time not only becaus of this

Comment: remove textbox1_TextChanged from Form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. Re-create the event handler in your Form1.cs file.
2. Delete line 53 in Form1.Designer.cs

This error normally occurs when you create an event, and then delete the event handler manually.

Also, verify that you're not adding new controls before InitializeComponent() is called, inside Form1.cs.

Comment: 1) You can click on the textbox
2) Press F4 to bring up the properties window
3) Click on the events tab (Lightning Bolt top right)
4) Scroll to the TextChanged event, and delete the event handler name from the event textbox.  When I say manually, I mean you go into Form1.cs, and select the event handler method and delete it, or rename it.  The event handler delegate in Form1.Designer.cs does not get updated automatically unless you use refactor rename,